# Apply selectize.js to dynamically added interdependently dropdowns with formvalidation

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a bootstrap-based form where fields can be dynamically added or removed as well as validated using the formvalidation plugin! Furthermore I'm using selectize.js for two interdependently dropdowns! It is working so far but I don't know how to initialize selectize.js for the newly added dropdown!

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtrbh30k/) with all my code (interdependent dropdown not working)!

From [formvalidation.io](http://formvalidation.io/examples/selectize/) I found this way to initialize

```
$('#selectizeForm')
    .formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        excluded: ':disabled',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            frameworks: {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Please indicate 2-4 Javascript frameworks',
                        callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .find('[name="frameworks"]')
        .selectize({
            plugins: ['remove_button'],
            delimiter: ',',
            persist: false,
            create: function(input) {
                ...
                };
            }
        })
        // Revalidate the frameworks field when it is changed
        .on('change', function(e) {
            $('#selectizeForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'frameworks');
        })
        .end();
```

but with this approach I don't even get my interdependent dropdown working at all!

**I really appreciate any help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you still look forward answers. Anyways wanna share my experience. I had the similar issue.I realized that selectize initialization will work fine for static controls(textbox,dropdowns or div) because as soon as DOM(html) loaded
selectize js does its job for all bound IDs. Whereas for dynamic
controls, we need to invoke seletize function by events such as
"click", "mouseover". I had used mouseover event. It works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I still didn't find a solution to make it working. Would you please tell me how to invoke selective for a dynamically added field like in my JSFiddle?! I really appreciate any further help!